# How to select text in React Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library

Using react testing library I am testing a text editor and would like to highlight text then click a button (that bolds the text)

How do I do that with React Testing Library

```
const boldButton = screen.getByTestId('editor-bold-button');
const textElement = screen.getByTestId('text-editor').children[0].children[0];

//<- Highlight text simulating click and drag on paragraph element.

//Click Bold Button
fireEvent.click(boldButton);
```